# Excel 2013 - formula to hide a series in a chart based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible to hide a series in a chart automatically depending on another cell's value.

*Edit:* 
I am building a dashboard for social media analytics with charts for different metrics (impressions, engagements, etc.). I would like to allow the chart to be formatted (show different values, i.e. hide Twitter) based on the value in a drop down menu in the top column that will allow you to select and view metrics for either Twitter, LinkedIn, or both at the same time.

Example showing Impressions chart for Twitter & LinkedIn when dropdown selected should only be showing Twitter data in Q2:

[image: Example showing Impressions chart for Twitter in Q2]]

Right now, my back end has the static data for each platform for the year, and then smaller 3x3 tables with data from only the months that are in the quarter selected. The charts are built using this dynamic table.

I can hide a chart using macros, but the problem is that I'll have to create and include 3 separate charts (Twitter, LinkedIn, Both) instead of using just the one in that image that shows both, and hiding the series that is not selected.

To make this worse, I also have a feature that compares to the previous quarter results, so that would mean 3 more charts, for a total of 6, which will just weigh down the spreadsheet and create more work to build and format.

Open to any suggestions on how to have 1 chart that will dynamically hide either Twitter or LinkedIn when the dropdown menu is changed.

My closest solution is dynamically changing LinkedIn values to 0 when Twitter is selected, but this causes the bar graph to be off center from the label - it's minor, but still looking for a better solution.

Comment: If you add auto-filter, then a dropdown is added at the top of the list and controls the visibility of rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you chart is something like this:

[image]

1. Select cell `A1`
2. Click to `Data -> Sort & Filter -> Filter` your chart should now look like this:

[image]

3. Use the dropdowns at the top to filter out whatever series you want.

[image]

The chart should automatically stop displaying the hidden series

[image]

If it still displays the series, right click on the chart an choose "Select Data" from the dropdown menu, then click on "Hidden and Empty Cells in the resulting dialog box and make sure "Show data in hidden rows and columns is **un**checked:

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you for this. Part 2, then, would be: Do you have a formula that can automatically filter a table based on the value of a cell. I.e. =IF(A1="Facebook", HIDE TABLE COLUMN 1), "")....

Comment: Formulas only put values in the cell that contains them and cannot affect other cells. I am starting to think we are having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It may be useful for you to explain exactly what you have, and what you are trying to accomplish, along with providing sample data

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad, thank for you pointing that out. It's true I may have been having that problem. I updated the description with more detail. I would appreciate if you could have another look and let me know if it's not clear. Thank you!